# Trying to download .pdf .png anf .jpg from nytimes.com

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a simple Python scraper to grab some documents from a specific page on nytimes.com. It works, in the sense that it grabs, and formats all the URL's correctly, and attempts to download the files, and formats the name correctly.

But all I get are 1kb files. I can't figure out why. Here is my code:

```
import urllib2 
import urllib 
from cookielib import CookieJar

files = 'http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/11/25/us/evidence-released-in-michael-brown-case.html?_r=0' 
slashpos = 0

def getLinks(url):
    cj = CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    p = opener.open(url)
    result = []
    for line in p:
        for element in line.split():
            if element.startswith('href="http://gr'):
                if element.endswith('pdf"') or element.endswith('png"') or element.endswith('jpg"'):
                    result.append(element[6:])
                else:
                    continue
    for char in result:
        slashpos = char.rfind('/') + 1
        urllib.urlretrieve(char, char[slashpos:-1])

getLinks(files)
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you add a `print char` within your `for char in result:` loop, you'll notice that you are trying to download the url with a double quote on the end. That could be causing problems.

Comment: Ironically, I did that a couple times last night. I still didn't notice the double quotes ...

I guess I wasn't paying enough attention to the output exactly. I noticed it was pulling the correct URLs, and just moved on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use `result.append(element[6:-1])` instead of `result.append(element[6:])` (Avoids having double quotes in the url, the reason why downloads fail)
2) and for saving the file use `urllib.urlretrieve(char, char[slashpos:])` instead of `urllib.urlretrieve(char, char[slashpos:-1])`

Comment: GAH! I looked over that like twenty times last night!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved !! :D

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urlparse
from sys import argv
from cookielib import CookieJar

if len(argv) != 2:
    print "Usage:\n\tpython %s 'http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/11/25/us/evidence-released-in-michael-brown-case.html?_r=0'"%argv[0]
    exit()
url = argv[1]
urls =[]
try:
    cj = CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    html = opener.open(url)
except:
    print "[-] No such website"
    exit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    try: 
        tag["href"] = urlparse.urljoin(url, tag['href'])
        if tag['href'] not in urls and '.png' in tag['href'] or '.jpg'  in tag['href']:
            newpdf = tag['href'].split("/")
            name = newpdf[-1]
            resp = urllib2.urlopen(tag['href'])
            meta_data =  resp.info()
            fsize = int(meta_data.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
            print "Downloading --> %s \t size: %s "%(name, fsize)
            f = open(name, "wb")
            f.write(resp.read())
            f.close
            urls.append(tag["href"])
        else:
            print tag['href']
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print " User hit CTRL+C"
        exit()
    except:
        pass
```

Hopefully it would be helpful for you

Comment: Nice. I was really looking to make my code work, but thanks for the new method using BeatifulSoup :)